# Getting a None or empty list after scraping info

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Recently I have started learning web scraping using BeautifulSoup. I tried scraping some info from a job posting site and i am getting an empty list.
This is the code I am using:

`jobs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard')`

and this what the HTML code of the page looks like:

'''

`div class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard" id="p_0646f3976ea7cfd6" data-jk="0646f3976ea7cfd6" data-tn-component="organicJob"`

'''

Please tell me how to scrape this tag!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do post the HTML file .For some reason its not visible as of now.

Comment: yes made the changes

Comment: @VarunrajBelgaonkar: Welcome to SO - A bit more code would help to reproduce what you are doing, so please improve your question - [how to - minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks (URL of website, plugins, ...)

Comment: Are you able to extract all the div tags?

Comment: I guess the problem is that `jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard` is not a class name. There are multiple classes: `jobsearch-SerpJobCard`, `unifiedRow`, `row`, `result`, `clickcard`

Comment: @SreeramM: Yes using this code:  jobs = soup.find_all('div') a list of all div tags is extracted.

Comment: @zvone you are right its referencing multiple classes

Comment: @zvone:So referencing any one class out of those could work?

Comment: Do let me know wether the answer worked or not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using :

```
jobs=soup.find_all("div", ["jobsearch-SerpJobCard","unifiedRow","row","result","clickcard"])
```

or

```
jobs=find_all("div", class_=['jobsearch-SerpJobCard','unifiedRow','row','result','clickcard'])
```

Comment: It is guessing, the question do not contain enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah at this point I am just assuming things .You are right

Comment: @SreeramM  Yeah using that code all the div tags can be extracted !